# Best way to test FileNotFound handling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm relatively new to testing and still getting my head around some of the fundamentals. I have a method that I would like to test which basically creates a different file name if the supplied already exists (I've pasted the code below).

I need a way of testing that the method returns a different (but also unique) name if the file already exists. What's the best way of testing this within Visual Studio's unit testing? Is it to create a file as part of the test and then delete it or is there a better way?

```
public static FileInfo SafeFileName(this FileInfo value)
{
    if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

    FileInfo fi = value;

    //Check the directory exists -if it doesn't create it as we won't move out of this dir
    if (!fi.Directory.Exists)
        fi.Directory.Create();

    //It does so create a new name
    int counter = 1;
    string pathStub = Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.Length - fi.Extension.Length));

    // Keep renaming it until we have a safe filename
    while (fi.Exists)
        fi = new FileInfo(String.Concat(pathStub, "_", counter++, fi.Extension));

    return fi;
}
```

Comment: You can test all you want but this never going to be concurrency-safe.

Comment: Thanks Henk however that's not a concern for this particular scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two testing methods (using a Visual Studio unit testing project) for the two scenarios:

```
    // using System.IO;

    [TestMethod]
    public void WhenFileExists()
    {
        // Create a file
        string existingFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
        using (File.Open(existingFilename, FileMode.CreateNew)) { }

        // Check its existence
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(existingFilename));

        // Call method to be tested
        string newFilename = DummyCreateFile(existingFilename);

        // Check filenames are different
        Assert.AreNotEqual<string>(existingFilename, newFilename);

        // Check the new file exists
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(newFilename));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void WhenFileDoesNotExist()
    {
        // Get a filename but do not create it yet
        string existingFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());

        // Check the file does not exist
        Assert.IsFalse(File.Exists(existingFilename));

        // Call method to be tested
        string newFilename = DummyCreateFile(existingFilename);

        // Check the file was created with the filename passed as parameter
        Assert.AreEqual<string>(existingFilename, newFilename);

        // Check the new file exists
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(newFilename));
    }

    private string DummyCreateFile(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (File.Open(filename, FileMode.CreateNew)) { }
            return filename;
        }
        catch
        {
            string newFilename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
            using (File.Open(newFilename, FileMode.CreateNew)) { }
            return newFilename;
        }
    }
```

The tested method is slightly changed in that it takes (and returns) a string argument instead of FileInfo for simplicity reasons.

Comment: Thanks Sorin, would this not end up creating a stack of files though (i.e. one every time the test is run)?

Comment: Yes it would but, the files being created in Windows' temp directory, they should be deleted by the system at some point. Of course you could also make sure and add some code to delete them before exiting the test method.

Comment: Thanks Sorin that's a great help

Answer (score 3):

I think a better would be to use the .Net runtime:

```
 System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()
```

and get rid of the file name generation code all together.

[GetRandomFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Ritch we use that for temporary file names however we need to maintain a naming convention in this particular scenario (it's for data importing into another system)

Answer (score 0):

Use [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) Method.